# Opening multiple video embedded modals using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make multiple modals with jQuery in webflow and now am able to make just one, if i repeat the code it just sits on each other.

I have 8 link images that should open 8 different modal windows each containing its own embedded video from youtube and on close to close them as in  now it is still playing in the background. I am using the webflow.com js working on this for a week now new to js but because of this and forms started to study it my brain hurts :). Please help

Here is the html markup:

```
<div class="w-section modal-bg">
    <div class="w-clearfix modalw"><a href="#" class="close-modal">X</a>
      <div class="w-embed w-iframe">
        <iframe height="498" width="510" src="http://video1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="w-section modal-bg1">
    <div class="w-clearfix modalw"><a href="#" class="close-modal">X</a>
      <div class="w-embed w-iframe">
        <iframe height="498" width="510" src="http://video2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .modal-bg {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      z-index: 9999;
      display: none;
      width: auto;
      margin: 20px auto auto;
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .modalw{
      width: 50%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .close-modal {
      padding-right: 10;
      padding-left: 10px;
      float: right;
    }

    }
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-link').click(function() {
    $('.modal-bg').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.close-modal').click(function() {
    $('.modal-bg').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.toggle()` method?
Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-link').click(function() {
    $('.modal-bg').toggle();
  });
  $('.close-modal').click(function() {
    $('.modal-bg').toggle();
  });
});
```

You can also specify a duration time for the toggle like `.toggle(400)` where the number specified is in milliseconds to mimic the `.fadeIn()/.fadeOut()`
More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display).

Comment: thank you!! read about it yesterday but didn't see how to implement it in my situation thanks again !!

Comment: glad to help. If you wouldn't mind, would you mark my response as answering your question?